# Why can't I import opencv3 even though the package is installed?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, spyder, opencv3.1

I currently am running Python 3.5 and using Spyder from Anaconda as my IDE. I am running this on a Windows machine.

When I write `import cv3` at the top of my code, it returns the error `ImportError: No module named 'cv3'`

I attempted to install opencv3 again with the command `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3` in the Command Prompt. It is apparently already installed because it returned

```
Fetching package metabase...............
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Joey\Anaconda3:
# opencv3       3.1.0       py35_0      https://conda.binstar.org/menpo
```

Am I importing cv3 wrong? How do I fix this error?

---

**Update:** Tried `import cv3` instead of `import cv2` but got the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'cv2'`. The wording on the two errors is different, so python must acknowledge there is opencv installed but it does not work for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by using command `pip uninstall opencv-python` in the Command Prompt.

I have attempted several installations of opencv and I suppose one may have downloaded badly and Anaconda was attempting to read that one. I looked into the build of some of the other installations I attempted and some were for Python 2.7. Maybe that contributed to the error.

Thankfully, this worked. Now `import cv2` works perfectly. No errors.

Answer (score 21):

Ironically enough, the module is still called `cv2` because it doesn't represent the version of opencv but the actual C++ API underneath which is, to be contrasted from the C API, named - cv2... So try with: `import cv2`

Comment: When I tried `import cv2` I got the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'cv2'`. Which is different wording from the other error, but still does not work for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm... then it appears that it was badly installed. Apart from bad compiling, I'm guessing it was installed in a subfolder of a subfolder cv2 as it commonly happens, try `import cv2.cv2`. If it doesn't solve it, try checking where in the `site-packages` of your Python env. it picks it from.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same approach to install the package. However, I could not import the library using the name `opencv3`. I had to use `cv2` which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @zwer's answer, check the version of OpenCV after `import cv2`.

```
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0'
```

So basically it's calling the OpenCV3 library.