# How to get the duration of video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I can only get the number of frames `CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` using OpenCV.

However, I cannot find the parameter to get the duration of the video using OpenCV.

How to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The number of frame * frequency if I recall.

Comment: @Mathieu actually it's # of frames / frequency. (frequency has unit 1/sec) So a video with 60 frames and 30 Hz has a duration of 2 seconds.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

OpenCV is not designed to explore video metadata, so [`VideoCapture`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) doesn't have API to retrieve it directly.

You can instead "measure" the length of the stream: seek to the end, then get the timestamp:

```
>>> import cv2 as cv
>>> v = cv.VideoCapture('sample.avi')
>>> v.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 1)
True
>>> v.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
213400.0
```

Checking shows that this sets the point after the last frame (not before it), so the timestamp is indeed the exact total length of the stream:

```
>>> v.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
5335.0
>>>> v.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
5335.0

>>> v.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 0)
>>> v.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
0.0        # the 1st frame is frame 0, not 1, so "5335" means after the last frame
```

Comment: The call to `v.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` might not return correct value unless `v.read()` is called after setting a position, including seeking to the end. See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15749

Comment: @kfx I see. So this is new behavior in `4.1.2`. [When I'm at the end, I get wrong number even after `read()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15749#issuecomment-651399016); from [the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L1590-L1609), it looks like it's not supposed to require calling `read()` because it sets `picture_pts`. So this is a bug in my book.

Comment: It seems like seeking to the end of the stream with `CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO` doesn't work all the time depending on the video type (e.g. doesn't work with QuickTime .mov files). I'd use this with caution.

Answer (score 61):

In OpenCV 3, the solution is:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture("./video.mp4")
fps = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV v2.x used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
duration = frame_count/fps

print('fps = ' + str(fps))
print('number of frames = ' + str(frame_count))
print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
minutes = int(duration/60)
seconds = duration%60
print('duration (M:S) = ' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds))

cap.release()
```

Comment: Why do you import `cv2` when you begin your answer by saying that you are using OpenCV 3? Doesn't `cv2` mean OpenCV 2, or have I got this wrong?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye, this page should explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102738/why-cant-i-import-opencv3-even-though-the-package-is-installed

Answer (score 8):

> **Capture the video and output the duration is seconds**

```
import cv2 as cv
vidcapture = cv.VideoCapture('myvideo.mp4')
fps = vidcapture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
totalNoFrames = vidcapture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
durationInSeconds = totalNoFrames / fps

print("durationInSeconds:", durationInSeconds, "s")
```

Answer (score 5):

First calculate frame per second like this

```
import cv2 as cv
# cap = cv.VideoCapture...
fps = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

Then duration can be calculated as (number of frames) / (frames per second)

```
 duration = float(num_frames) / float(fps) # in seconds
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not always work. CAP_PROP_FPS comes from header data, it is not reliably calculated

Answer (score 2):

In my personal experience I've been using the OpenCV method.
Try this code:

```py
import cv2 as cv

def get_dur(filename):
    video = cv.VideoCapture(filename)
    fps = video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_count = video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    seconds = frame_count / fps
    minutes = int(seconds / 60)
    rem_sec = int(seconds % 60)
    return f"{minutes}:{rem_sec}"

print(get_dur("dafuck.mp4"))
```

Comment: You can use python's divmod function to calculate the quotient (minutes) and remainder (seconds) at once. For example for 100 s: minutes, seconds = divmod(100, 60)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a weird phenomenon that many video **DO NOT HAVE** as much frames as the `vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` gets.

I suppose that the video duration should be the *divided value of TOTAL FRAMES by FPS*, but it always mismatch. The video duration would be longer than we calculated. Considering what FFMPEG does, the original video might has some empty frames.

Hope this help.