# Python3 the duration is inconsistent between audio track and video

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, audio, video, librosa

I'm trying to extract audio and visual information from a video. As we known, the visual and audio information must be paired. Thus, I check the information from **OpenCV (visual part)** and **librosa (audio part)**. However, **the total duration is not the same**.

```py
import cv2
import librosa


print(cv2.__version__) ## 3.4.1

vid_path = '001167.mp4'
audio, audio_rate = librosa.load(vid_path, sr=16000, mono=False)
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)


vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO,1)
video_length = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
audio_length = librosa.get_duration(y=audio,sr=audio_rate)
print(audio_length,video_length/1000)
```

Result: `Audio: 10.005 sec`, `Video: 9.0924 sec`

The audio duration is longer.

Comment: Have you tried it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048111/how-to-get-the-duration-of-video-using-cv2) way instead?

Comment: @RickM. Yes. I did this before. Thanks you anyways.